# Fabric.js insertAt not working as expected

Tags: fabricjs

I want to make two groups of objects as layers with fabric.js. But although I put the second one with a lower z-index, it is still on top. See the code example below. What is wrong?

```js
var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('canvas');

var render_items = function() {
  var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    left: 25,
    top: 10,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'red'
  });
  var layerA = new fabric.Group([rect1], {
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
  });
  canvas.insertAt(layerA, 100);
  var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    left: 30,
    top: 20,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'blue'
  });
  var layerB = new fabric.Group([rect2], {
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
  });
  canvas.insertAt(layerB, 50);
}();
```

```css
#canvas {
 border:1px solid #000000; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.5/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric.JS doesn't really have true z-index functionality as you see with css. Instead, objects on the canvas work like an array where the index of each object determines where it sits in the stacking order. Using `canvas.insertAt()` lets you specify a specific index to insert the object in the array, and the length of the array is always determined by how many objects there are in your canvas.

Inserting an object at an index of 0 will therefore shift the other objects within the array so that the new object is rendered at the bottom of the stacking order.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('canvas');

var render_items = function() {
  var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    left: 25,
    top: 10,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'red'
  });
  var layerA = new fabric.Group([rect1], {
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
  });
  canvas.insertAt(layerA, 0);
  var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    left: 30,
    top: 20,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'blue'
  });
  var layerB = new fabric.Group([rect2], {
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
  });
  canvas.insertAt(layerB, 0);
}();
```

```css
#canvas {
 border:1px solid #000000; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.5/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```